# One APNS certificate for multiple iOS apps

Tags: ios, heroku, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

we are currently developing iOS applications for different clients.

We have one template application and different derived applications (slightly different layout, but the functionality is nearly the same).

We've chosen to host our backend on heroku and use the PubNub-Addon (with pub-and sub to different channels) to handle push-Notifications.

http://www.pubnub.com

This works just fine for one application.
But if we have multiple applications we need to create one pub nub "application" for each iOS application, because we need to upload the PEM-File (APNS certificate) of the iOS app to the PubNub application which is quite cumbersome.

**Is there a possibility that multiple iOS app use the same PEM-File (APNS certificate)?** So that we can use one PubNub Application for all the different iOS apps?

Do you have any other suggestions how this problem can be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No its not possible to use same PEM-File for multiple application.
You would need to create separate PEM file for each application. Because apple push notification server(APNS) can’t identify your different applications by one PEM certificate.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. You're correct. We now create one PubNub Application for each app.

Comment: In the near future, PubNub's Account Dashboard will allow you to upload multiple APNS push certs on a single key set.